# How can I get nested tests to ouput text properly in specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2

I have been having trouble getting the text of my specification to be output properly. I will use part of an example from the specs2 documenation:

```
class TaggedSpecification extends Specification {
  "this is some introductory text" >> {
    "and the first group of examples" >> {
      "example 1" in success
      "example 2" in success
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect this to show up like this in the terminal when I run it:

```
TaggedSpecification
this is some introductory text
  and the first group of examples
   + example 1
   + example 2
```

Instead, it is showing up like this:

```
TaggedSpecification
and the first group of examples
 + example 1
 + example 2
```

Why is the introductory text and indentation being eliminated? I thought that ">>" was the same as "should" but did not add the should text after the string. I have been unable to find anything in the documentation that clarifies this for me.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @Eric Good question.  I wasn't really sure.  I am using Play and didn't have to add any dependencies to use specs2. When I start play I see: `play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_25)`

Comment: Can you try to add the latest specs2 2.3.4 to your dependencies?

Comment: @Eric That did it. It's showing up properly now.

Comment: Cool, I added an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to the latest specs2 version, 2.3.4. Since the introduction of "interpolated specifications" in 2.0 there have been some various refactorings which have introduced display bugs.